# Geth never fully sync

Tags: go-ethereum

on an aws machine, lighthouse say it is synced.
but Geth is not, for a few days now its syncing but keep the same distance between current and highest block(from eth_syncing response):

```
"currentBlock":"0xf93a7a"
"highestBlock":"0xf93ac2"
```

Geth recent print is that:

```
Jan 04 12:50:35 ip-172-31-23-187 geth[47297]: INFO [01-04|12:50:35.949] Forkchoice requested sync to new head    number=16,333,536 hash=b5851f..98ff42
Jan 04 12:50:36 ip-172-31-23-187 geth[47297]: INFO [01-04|12:50:36.599] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed="338.72µs"  number=16,333,536 hash=b5851f..98ff42
Jan 04 12:50:39 ip-172-31-23-187 geth[47297]: INFO [01-04|12:50:39.690] State heal in progress                   accounts=2,445,539@142.68MiB slots=5,617,934@408.10MiB codes=7751@41.61MiB nodes=56,687,888@10.75GiB pending=23018
```

Comment: It can because of the memory size you assigned to the running Geth. What is your system's RAM and how much RAM you assigned to this Geth?

Comment: hey, thanks for the comment, i checked and ulimit -a says 'unlimited' memory size
and 'free --mega' says i have 9595 mega free

Comment: You're welcome, The most important reason for Geth not syncing is memory consumption exceeding the system capacity. You should pay attention to this point that Geth is programmed with the Go lang and it is a property of this lang that it consumes twice the amount of memory allocated to it. So, check your system's RAM and see how much memory size Geth should consume for your system. Assign half this size to Geth.

Comment: what do you mean assign memory to geth?
it is unlimited and there is more memory available in the system.
what am i missing?

Comment: Did you use `--cache` flag when you did run Geth? if yes, what number did you write after that? You should use `--cache <a number in MB>` to determine how much of memory should be assigned to Geth when it is running. If you didn't use this flag it sets the default value, that is 1024 MB. Try Geth by this flag instead unlimited and let I know the result.

Comment: ok restarted geth with cache 6000

Comment: still same issue, after few hours still not synced

Comment: What is memory size of your system?

Comment: so the issue was the ports for the tcp was closed so it could not get many peers